# "Ascii85":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, ascii

Having troubles with a rails install, keeping getting an error for this ascii85 string error

```
(/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:277:in `==': undefined method `name' for "Ascii85":String (NoMethodError)).
```

If anyone ever got through this.

Comment: Are you building rails from source? Do you have all the dependencies installed?

Comment: Same install setup  as previous server install, only here is the newest ubuntu version 64bits. Dependencies are here, i was using the rails 2.3.5 version wich now lacks "mutex" when trying tu run script/server.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like a bug in RubyGems: http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29188&group_id=126&atid=575

If you can manage with an older version roll back to 1.5.3:

```
gem update --system 1.5.3
```

Comment: +10000. Big thanx !Weird problems using mongrel and mongrel cluster after that; had to get rid of it and use passenger instead.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Rails to version 2.3.14 solved this problem.